# How to obfuscate a unity3d game (android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I tried obfuscating a unity3d game (android). I tried taking the apk, unzipping it, obfuscating the dll and then tried to repack the apk without success. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this tutorial?

http://www.4infinity.com.hk/tutorial/code_obfuscation

or Eazfuscator.NET

http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/features/gaming-technologies#unity

Comment: Eazfuscator.NET said they don't really support unity mono on android.